# Countably many projections on more than continuous vector space with trivial commutant?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, representation-theory

Is there such an example?

An $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space $V$ of dimension strictly more than the continuous $c=|2^{\mathbb{N}}|$, and a numerable set of commuting $\mathbb{F}_2$ projections $\{\pi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that the only $\mathbb{F}_2$-automorphism of $V$ that commutes with all the projections is the identity?